# Different Data types Order By in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one situation where i want to sort table on from time but if the status of the row is suppose **abc** i want to order by these records by **status**.
Requirement is all vacant records needs to be display at the bottom and after that in top records i have to display records as per from time asc.

status is varchar , fromtime is decimal 
e.g. status- vacant,occupied,current etc.
fromtime- 13.00,14.30,07.30 etc.

```
select * from tbluser order by case when [status]='vacant' then [status] else fromtime end
```

i am getting below error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'vacant' to data type int
```

i have 2 columns one with integer and one with varchar. works with varchar. but not with decimal
but when i use below condition it works
[from time] is varchar-

```
Case When Status = 'Vacant' Then Status Else [from time] End
```

Comment: `When Status='Vacant' Then Status` means that that side of the `CASE` is always returning a constant value - `Vacant` - so you could substitute that with any other constant value, say `1000000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cast in your query as `cast(fromtime as varchar)`

So your query becomes

```
 select 
       * 
 from 
       tbluser 
 order by 
       case 
           when [status]='vacant' then [status] 
           else cast(fromtime as varchar) end
```

### Edit 1

Here is a similar post which may help you

[Understanding a Sql Server Query - CASE within an ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070276/understanding-a-sql-server-query-case-within-an-order-by-clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbluser
ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN [status]='vacant' then [status]
             ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), fromtime)
         END
```